# Why does casting to int not floor all doubles in C

Tags: c, floating-point

Given the C code:

```
#include <math.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
int main(){  
 int i;  
 double f=log(2.0)/log(pow(2.0,1.0/2.0));  
 printf("double=%f\n",f);  
 printf("int=%d\n",(int) f);  
}
```

I get the output:

```
double=2.000000
int=1
```

f is apparently at least 2.0. Why is the cast value not 2?

Comment: It seems like the premise of the question is false, from the answers. The real "problem" is that printf rounds floating point numbers.

Comment: You might also consider a case where int has the same size as double and you do something like `log((double)int_64_variable)`. I am more inclined doing this on a piece of paper than writing a c program for this. ;)

Comment: Also note that casting to `int` does *not* floor but rather truncates toward zero.  This matters for negative values.

Comment: Title of the question should really be "why does `printf` round this particular double like this?"...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because the value of the double was less than 2

```
double=1.99999999999999978
int=1
```

Try it but this time add some precision

```
#include <math.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
int main(){  
 int i;  
 double f=log(2.0)/log(pow(2.0,1.0/2.0));  
 printf("double=%0.17f\n",f);  
 printf("int=%d\n",(int) f);  
}
```

Confusing as hell the first time you experience it. Now, if you try this

```
#include <math.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
int main(){  
 int i;  
 double f=log(2.0)/log(pow(2.0,1.0/2.0));  
 printf("double=%0.17f\n",f);  
 printf("int=%d\n",(int) f);  
 printf("int=%d\n", (int)round(f));
}
```

It will correctly round the value.  If you look in the man page (on a mac at least) you'll see the following comment...

```
round, lround, llround -- round to integral value, regardless of rounding direction
```

What do they mean by direction, it's all specified in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). If you check the [different ways to round to an integer...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer) floor is mentioned as rounding towards `-ve infinity` which is in this case was towards `1` :)

Answer (score 7):

Integer does not take a rounded up value but makes a truncation. So, if f is equal to 1.999999999999[..]9, the int value will be 1.

Also, as the double wants to be the more accurate possible, he will take a rounded up value considering the number of characters he can show, which is 2.000000.

Answer (score 7):

Floating point types are unable to represent some numbers exactly. Even though mathematically, the [calculation should be exactly 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(2)%2Flog(2%5E0.5)), with IEEE754 floating points, the result turns out to be slightly less than 2. For more information see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate).

If you increase the precision of your output by specifying `%.20f` instead of just `%f`, you will see that the number is not exactly 2, and that when printing with less accuracy, the result is simply rounded.

When converting to an `int` however, the full accuracy of the floating point type is used, and since it comes to just under 2, the result when converting to an integer is 1.